# SpriteKit accelerometer not always accurate or maybe over sensitive

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift3

I am implementing motion in my game using the following code:

if motionManager.isAccelerometerAvailable == true {

```
    motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates(to: OperationQueue.current!, withHandler: {

        data, error in

        let currentX = self.player.position.x

        self.destX = currentX + CGFloat((data?.acceleration.x)! * 200)

    })

}
```

Then in the update(_ currentTime: CFTimeInterval) function:

```
let action = SKAction.moveTo(x: destX, duration: 0.2)

        self.player.run(action)
```

The problem is that it seems really sensitive and the sprite will sometimes go the opposite way to its tilt and just seems all over the place, I think it has to do with the tilt of the device, I just want to detect side to side motion. Am I missing something?

Comment: My guess is you are constantly adding actions that overlap each other,  assign a key to the run action and it will cancel any actions with the previous key

Comment: `self.player.run(action, withKey:"Move")`

Comment: Thanks for that, this now doesn't respond at all to movement with this code in...

Comment: it is not moving at all?

Comment: Nope nothing now I have added withKey:

Comment: Full code is here http://pastebin.com/WpA48fAU if that helps

Comment: I have this code run(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("phaserDown3.mp3", waitForCompletion: false)) that plays a sound when 2 objects collide, it seems that when this line is removed the motion is greatly improved - it's baffling me to be honest

Comment: I will have to write a quick demo for this,  I am almost positive this works,  My guess is that the move amount is so tiny in the first iteration that it does not move at all

Comment: that is because it is loading the MP3 at that point,  you need to preload

Comment: Ok great, pre loading the mp3 works fine in the most part and improves the stability of the motion but after a little it still messes up somewhat, I assume this is what you were saying earlier about the actions overlapping?

Comment: yes,  I will look into why it is not moving

Comment: Thank you so much Knight0fDragon - really appreciate your input

Comment: @Knight0fDragon is this for reals: "assign a key to the run action and it will cancel any actions with the previous key" If so... this is another of those WONDERFUL gems of knowledge you seem to be walking around with. How does this work? Where did you learn this... please tell me MORE!

Comment: so I wrote my test, move to works fine when constantly being replaced, instead of doing the moveTo in the action, do it in the accelerometer update

Comment: @Confused, yes, this is how dictionaries work. replacing the instance at a certain key with a new instance will cause the old instance to release from memory providing there are no other references holding it.  Since the sprite will no longer have a reference to this action, it will no longer use the action

Comment: @AppleTattooGuy my theory is the accelerometer update is being called after the gamescene update. so it may be possible that you are always standing

Comment: @AppleTattooGuy add this to line 34 `let phaserDown = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("phaserDown3.mp3", waitForCompletion: false)` and whenever you need to play the sound, just do `run(phaserDown)`

Comment: @Confused they are basic types, if you ever see withKey, you can bet it is a dictionary of some type, if it is atIndex, you can bet it is an array of some type

Comment: argh. WOW! I had NO IDEA! I just thought it was some kind of internal system for making the finding of objects more confusing than using references. I have been (mostly) completely avoiding withKey: "String" cause it just seemed so arbitrary. Your insight is WISDOMICAL! I think I'll have a play with it, and stop using boolean flags all over the place.

Comment: @Confused, now when I say dictionary, I do not mean `Dictionary` so do not think you can just go ahead and cast it to this type,  it just behaves like a dictionary behaves,  who knows what it is really using on the back end

Comment: So, the take away is this? -> it's some kind of dictionary sort of thing in the background, and so long as you use the same withKey, on the same object, you're overwriting the old Action that had that same key, and can think of this as 'starting anew' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to fetch your motion data directly in the update method of your scene, so its updated 60 times a second. I never got good results using the handler, it is always sluggish there even if you set the interval very low.

```
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
     if let data = motionManager.accelerometerData {
          let currentX = player.position.x
          destX = currentX + CGFloat((data.acceleration.x) * 200)
          ...
     }
 }
```

You might have to adjust the 200 to get the desired result. I would also reduce the SKAction duration, 0.2 is too long. Alternatevely try updating your Sprite position directly without using an SKAction.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the other part of the tutorial you're probably getting this code from here: https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/move-sprites-accelerometer-spritekit-swift  in that he feels the need to handle the negative data in a weird way:

```
        let currentX = self.player.position.x

   if data.acceleration.x < 0 {
          self.destX = currentX + CGFloat(data.acceleration.x * 100)
        }

   else if data.acceleration.x > 0 {
          self.destX = currentX + CGFloat(data.acceleration.x * 100)
        }
```

And the clue to why this might be an issue, and the entire "tutorial" a myopic dream, is that he's using the creation of SKActions in the update() to power movement.

That doesn't seem right, at all.

There's two other good ways to move things, with motion data:

1. Apply forces that reflect the angle of the device, to the object
2. Change the direction and strength of gravity affecting the object based on device angle

I'd consider both to be vastly superior to the Action technique of responding to motion information, but I could be wrong about this.

Comment: His accelerometer code is fine and doesn't have the if statement,  I would just delete this answer.  The tutorial is also correct, no idea why they would do that though

Comment: Thanks for the input here. The main issue I am now having from playing around with this is that when the sound is playing using run(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("phaserDown3.mp3", waitForCompletion: false)) it is messing up the motion, I have now moved the loading of the sound outside the conflict function and it is much better but every so often the character will 'stick' to either side and tilting the device will do nothing then after 30 seconds or so it is fine again - as soon as I disable this sound it works fine, really strange....